# Modernizr.borderradius is TRUE on device whitout support css border-radius

Tags: html, modernizr, css

I have a div element with css border-radius. My Android 2.2.1 Device with default browser (webkit/533.1) dosn't support border-radius, so i try use modernizr to detect this feature. Problem is that modernizr return true thought border-radius dosn't work. What can I do now?
How can I detect it?

```
<style>
    .border{
       -moz-border-radius: 100%;
       -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
       -khtml-border-radius: 100%;
       border-radius: 100%;          
    }

   .div{
      background: red;
      width:100px;
      height: 100px;                
   }
</style>


<div class="border div"></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  
     if (!Modernizr.borderradius) {
       alert ("css border radius is not supported");
       }
  })
</script>
```

Demo on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7NvLM/

Comment: well, if Modernizr reports border-radius as working, than it probably has some basic support. I guess the support is limited to  pixel values while percent values don't work. See here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/borderradius.js - Modernizr tests with a pixel value. Or your browser returns something like `0` for an unknown property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius), `border-radius` *is* supported by the Android 2.2 browser. 2.1 requires a prefix but is also supported. Therefore, Modernizr is reporting correctly.

However CanIUse also notes that Android 2.3 (and presumably earlier) does not support percentage values for the property. That'll be why it's not working for you.

I guess Modernizr is looking at basic feature support (which it has). You may need to write your own more specific test for this particular case.

Comment: I did not notice the known issues of percentage values. Is not problem rewrite the % to px. Thank you very much!